# Unexpected token ":" with JSON returned from node and express

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, ajax, express

I'm building a small web service with Node.js and Express, and I'm running into a bit of a problem. Everything seems to work perfectly fine, until I true to use it with Ajax in a browser. If I run it in Postman, I get:

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "data": [
    {
      "GUID": "2f779770-9e1c-415f-9518-ff7fd7d6631c",
      "name": "The Revolver",
      "description": "Rye heavy bourbon, coffee liqueur, orange bitters, orange garnish.",
      "active": 1,
      "categories": [
        "94162f2e-3b2f-4521-a543-068ed6c81011"
      ]
    },
    {
      "GUID": "f05a33ad-e684-4ae0-804c-0c1a61b9945d",
      "name": "Jack Rose",
      "description": "Laird's Applejack, Grenadine, Lemon, Peychaud's bitters, Lemon twist",
      "active": 1,
      "categories": []
    }
  ]
}
```

Headers includes 
`Content-Type →application/json; charset=utf-8`

But when I make the ajax call Chrome says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"

I'm using `res.json({status: "ok", data: result})` to return the response from Express. I've also tried `res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');` with no luck.

Any ideas?

Edit: here's the ajax call:

```
function getDrinks(){
  $.ajax({
    url: serviceURL + "getDrinks",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(result){
      if (result.status=="ok"){
        var tableHTML=""
        for (var i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
          var drink=result.data[i]
          tableHTML+="<tr><td>"+drink.name+"</td></tr>"
        }
        tableHTML="<table>"+tableHTML+"</table>"
        $("#drinksContainer").html(tableHTML);
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Show the ajax call

Comment: Is the client expecting JSON or JSON-P for the response to its Ajax request? This error can occur when JSON is parsed as JavaScript (which JSON-P is). The braces are interpreted as a block rather than as an object initializer and, in that context, a colon isn't permitted after a string literal.

Comment: OOoh elaboroate, @JonathanLonowski ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client and server will need to agree on whether to use JSON or JSON-P. The two formats are related but aren't interchangeable.

Currently, the client is expecting JSON-P...

```
dataType: "jsonp",
```

While the server is responding with JSON...

```
res.json({status: "ok", data: result})
```

---

For JSON-P, the server's response should include *Padding* around the JSON data, consisting of a `callback` name and parenthesis.

```
var json = JSON.stringify({status: "ok", data: result});
res.send(req.query.callback + '(' + json + ')');
```

Express also defines [`res.jsonp()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.jsonp) to simplify this.

```
res.jsonp({status: "ok", data: result});
```

And, jQuery will provide a generated callback name for you, typically consisting of the version of jQuery you're using, a random number, and a timestamp. With that, the response should be something like:

```
jQuery32101234567890123456_1496534400000({"status":"ok","data":...});
```